# Past Simple or Past Continuous - "make friends"

Tags: tense

"While they were travelling abroad, they were making a lot of friends" or "while they were travelling abroad, they made a lot of friends"

Comment: Take your pick. Which do you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

Repeating the continuous form in contexts like *While [verb1-ing], subject is [verb2-ing]* is relatively unusual. And precisely *because* it's a less common choice, native speakers will go to some lengths to infer a specific *meaning* to that choice (***if*** they know it was a ***competent*** speaker's deliberate choice of phrasing).

The assumed implication will normally be based on the idea that repeating the continuous form expresses a stronger link between ***verb1*** and ***verb2*** than mere "simultaneous activity" as already conveyed by ***while*** (or similar).

Thus in the *exact* cited example, I'd probably assume the speaker wanted to imply that the fact that they were traveling abroad somehow made it *easier* (or otherwise more likely) for them to make new friends. But it's not necessarily a good example. For more straightforward alternatives, consider...

> 1: *While studying for my degree, I wasn't earning much money*
>    2: *While working as an unpaid lifeguard, I'm getting a good suntan*

...where we might reasonably infer ***because*** linking "downside" low wages to studying in #1, and ***although*** linking "upside" getting a tan to doing a job without pay in #2. Note that in other contexts, different relationships between the two activities might make more sense.